# Safety of using Reaper extensions

Tags: cockos-reaper

An important feature of Reaper DAW is large database of user-written extensions. How safe they are to use, regarding either malicious intent or bugs? What is the extent of the potential danger, e.g. can an extension possibly install a virus or delete files? What reasonable steps one may and should undertake to avoid installing dangerous extensions?

*I understand this is a computer security question, but Reaper is music software, so I think this is the site where I can find users who are competent to answer.*

Comment: "Don't Fear the Reaper". Just make sure you install the "more cowbell" extension.

Comment: The title of this question makes it seem like it belongs on agriculture.stackecxchange.com.